# My USB ports are not working in Debian, they only charge connected devices

Tags: linux, usb, debian

This is my `lsusb` result:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58be Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

What can I do?

Comment: Please edit your question: It would probably help to know what make and model system you are running Debian on.

Comment: Was this `lsusb` result obtained after you connected some device(s)? What device(s)? Do you see anything relevant in `dmesg` just after you connect a device? What do you see for what device? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out.
I forgot I asked a question.